# Get-Help cannot find the Help files for ServiceFabric module

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric

I installed the Azure Service Fabric SDK and I wanted to get some help information on some of the commands:

```
Get-Help Connect-ServiceFabricCluster
```

It returns the following output under remarks:

```
REMARKS
    Get-Help cannot find the Help files for this cmdlet on this computer. It is displaying only partial help.
      -- To download and install Help files for the module that includes this cmdlet, use Update-Help.
```

I ran Update-Help -Module ServiceFabric in an administrator window and I still get this error.

How can I get the help to work for the ServiceFabric powershell commands?

Comment: [On MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt125965.aspx)

Comment: I know I can get help on MSDN. I want to get help in powershell.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran Update-Help successfully from an admin window, are you still seeing this problem?  You could try running Update-Help -Module ServiceFabric -Force  to force update.

Sounds like an issues with PowerShell Update-Help.  [This post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/powershell-get-help-detailed-cannot-find-help/68cd64b6-ce4d-4a4c-875b-18d5ad663f1d) provides a little more info and a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with core commands, i.e. I couldn't get detailed help for Get-Command.

In my case it helped specifying the locale to en-US when running Update-Help as there seems to be a Problem with the fallback to en-US when no other help files can be found.

Command it worked with:

```
Update-Help -UICulture en-US
```

See also:
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6217